# Pygame how to "place" an image when you press a key

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, random, time

class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):
        bg = pygame.image.load('data/bg.png')
        select = pygame.image.load('data/select.png')
        block1 = pygame.image.load('data/enemy1.png')
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        while 1:
            clock.tick(30)

            spriteList = []

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                spriteList.append(block1, (0, 0))

            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            print(mouse)
            screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
            screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(select, (mouse))
            for sprite in spriteList:
                screen.blit(sprite[0], sprite[1])

            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WINDOWWIDTH = 640
    WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Sandbox')
    Game().main(screen)
```

I'm trying to make it so where you move the mouse a box follows it. Then when you click the space key, "place" an image where you pressed space and then leave it there and be able to place another image somewhere else without effecting the first one. I tried using `spriteList` but I am kind of confused on where to go from here. 
And when I run it I get an error saying: `.append() takes one argument (2 given)`

Answer (score 1):

Add a tuple to your list. Also, store the mouse position, not (0, 0). Change

```
spriteList.append(block1, (0, 0))
```

to

```
spriteList.append((block1, mouse))
```

Also, you could rewrite

```
for sprite in spriteList:
            screen.blit(sprite[0], sprite[1])
```

to

```
for (img, pos) in spriteList:
            screen.blit(img, pos)
```

Comment: Thanks! It displays block1 where the mouse is now but when I stop pressing the space bar is doesn't. Is there a way I can make it so that it places block1 at the position of the mouse and stays there after I release the space bar?

Comment: Yes, put the line `spriteList = []` *before* the `while` loop. Otherwise you clear that list every frame.